# elements of Z[x]/2z[x] and (Z/2Z)[x]

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Okay, it may be very easy the answer of this question but here we are. I saw a theorem that says: "If $I$ is and ideal of $R$, then $\frac{R[x]}{I[x]}$ is isomorphic to $\frac{R}{I}[x]$ as rings".
The proof follows from 1st Isomorphism Theorem for rings and I can relatively understand that. I tried to write down an example of this theorem to see its meaning better and I let $R=\Bbb{Z}$ and $I=\Bbb{2Z}$. But the elements of $\frac{\Bbb{Z}[x]}{\Bbb{2Z}[x]}$ and $\Bbb{\frac{Z}{2Z}}[x]$ I have a difficulty to write down. If $\Bbb{\frac{Z}{2Z}}[x]$ is the ring of polynomials that have coefficients in $\Bbb{\frac{Z}{2Z}}$, how can a coefficient be in the form $\left\{1+\Bbb{2Z}\right\}$? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just imagine the polynomials as finite sequences (e.g. $(1,0,1,2,0,0,\dots) \cong 1+X^2+2X^3$). In the later ($(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)[X]$) you have sequences of $0$s and $1$s, on the first one you have integer sequences, where you quotient out even sequences. I think this is a little bit easier to imagine.

Comment: Just because in $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$, $1+2\mathbf Z$ is *one* element. You must not think of it as a *subset* of $\mathbf Z$, exactly the same as when you think of the rational number $1/3$, you don't think of it as the equivalence class $$\Bigl\{\frac13,\frac 26,\frac39,\dotsm\Bigr\}.$$

Comment: Okay, I understood an element as the form {1+2$\Bbb{Z}$} but I dont understand elements of the first one. If p(x) is an element of Z[x]/2Z[x], what is general form of p(x)? Or any example for p(x)?